# referring to the object in a callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, callback

My instruction is as :

```
map.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mapOnMouseMove, false);

function mapOnMouseMove (e) {
   // here : this refers to the canvas of the map object
   // i want to refer to the map (is there a way ?)
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not attaching an event directly to map's mousemoe event?

Answer (score 1):

You could trick `this` to refer to `map` like this:

```
map.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", canvasOnMouseMove, false);

function canvasOnMouseMove (e) {
   mapOnMouseMove.call(map, e);
}

function mapOnMouseMove (e) {
   // here : this refers to the map object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a bound function (where the value of `this` is your `map` object):

```
map.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mapOnMouseMove.bind(map), false);
```

But note that since `bind` is an ES5 method, it's not supported in older browsers. The MDN article linked to above provides a polyfill that you will probably want to use as well.

Comment: what about the interoperability ?

Comment: @Oddant - As stated, MDN provides code for a polyfill that should allow you to use `bind` in older browsers.